# "iPhone has denied the launch request." can not debug

Tags: ios, xcode

Now it does not show up the Entitlements error. Instead it shows Build Succeeded but while launching the app on device, following error is thrown "iPhone has denied the launch request." This error is coming on every xcode project on every iOS device. I've tried countless other "correct" methods.It still does not work.

Comment: @BenAvery   i tried some ways ,but i can not debug.

Comment: Have the same issue. I've tried every single solution from SO which I can find, but no luck :(

Comment: @RuslanKolosovskyi Same situation... no luck...

Comment: Use the paid account  do not have this issue ,but free account  can not debug.